# Virtual Address space and physical address space of 4GB RAM

Tags: virtual-machine, virtual-memory

With a 4GB size RAM, do you have 2^32 address space in the physical memory? Then what would be the size of virtual memory?

Comment: Won't be [SuperUser](http://superuser.com) a better place for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, 4GB of RAM is 2^32. 2^32/1024/1024/1024 = 4.

Virtual memory isn’t connected to physical memory size. It’s limited by the available storage space.

Comment: Thanks. Can you confirm the first question please?

Comment: Isn't virtual memory size related to the bitness of the machine? Like the maximum addressable memory in 32 bit machine is `2^32 -1`, so virtual memory cannot be more than 4 GB (provided that there is enough hard disk space available all the time to accommodate the pages)?